# GitLab CI - Automated builds only on schedule

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab

After a long search I couldn't find a way to do this, so now I wonder if it's possible to disable automated builds when a merge/push is done to master, allowing it to happen only based on a scheduled pipeline, so far I've tried:

`when: manual`

The above disables automated builds, but on scheduled builds it also expects a user input allowing it happen.

`except: master`

Also disables automated builds, even for scheduled pipelines (master branch)

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Use `schedules` keyword instead of branch name. Gitlab understands it for scheduled pipelines. Like:

```
job:
  ..........
  only:
    - schedules
```

Doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified